# Android ".apk" deployment from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I use Eclipse IDE for developing Android applications. I have done pretty much the same things what is written on Internet to download and setup Android SDK on Eclipse. I allowed installation of non market apps also checked USB debugging option.

I am trying to run my very basic Android application on Galaxy Tab 10.1. When I start the application and press Run button on Eclipse.

on the console of Eclipse the following is written:

```
[2011-12-04 20:14:09 - dene] Android Launch!
[2011-12-04 20:14:09 - dene] adb is running normally.
[2011-12-04 20:14:09 - dene] Performing com.berkay.dene.DeneActivity activity launch
[2011-12-04 20:14:13 - dene] Uploading dene.apk onto device '4289143415F3397'
[2011-12-04 20:14:13 - dene] Installing dene.apk...
```

but it stops here and does not proceed.

On the other hand, when I use the adb tool and use command line

adb install

it successfully installs my program to my device.
but this way is quite time consuming. what can be the problem?

Comment: seen this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html ?? just asking to be sure

Comment: yes i have also installed usb drivers for windows and changed my manifest file.